# What is the last digit of $7^{3553}$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I just want to check that I did this right. So for powers of $7$, they have a pattern of:
$$7^1 = 7, \;
7^2 = 9, \;
7^3 = 3, \;
7^4 = 1, \;
7^5 = 7$$

So for $3553$, I divide it by $4$ and get $888.25$. So it has a remainder of 1/4 which means the last digit is the beginning of a new cycle, so it is $7$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: You've been here for two and half years, it's about time that you learned some MathJax/LaTeX so your posts could look a lot better.

Comment: If you know *Euler's theorem*,  it is shorter.

Comment: @Bernard: shorter ? How ? The OP's method costs $3$ one-by-one-digit multiplies and a modulo $4$.

Comment: No multiplication required with Euler's $\varphi$.